# Could n't connect mongodb atlas from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect mongodb from node js.Below code i am using.

```js
    const mongodb = require('mongodb');
    const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    const mongoConnect = callback => {
        MongoClient.connect(
                'mongodb+srv://lalit_rout2012:QYhGtmSyw3bCBIWt@cluster0.s9jpclh.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
            )
            .then(client => {
                console.log('Connected!');
                callback(client);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    module.exports = mongoConnect;
```

Error i am getting
[image]

Please suggest.Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing requires node 14 or above. what is your node version

Comment: Posting credentials is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks for your concern.But this is for learning purpose no usefull data present in DB.